# netlogo how to set minimum separation for the turtle follow the leader

Tags: netlogo

i tried to make an agents(white) follow the leader(black) when emergency happen. the problem is, when emergency happen, agents will follow the leader, however they overlap each other. how to make sure they do not overlap each other when follow the leader. i did tried on use separation rule in flocking, it doesn't work.Really need to know on how to fix this. thanks for the help

```
turtles-own 
[
leader? 
leader
]


to setup
clear-all
reset-ticks

ask n-of population patches with [ pcolor = blue]
[sprout 1
[ set color white
set size 1
set shape "person"
set leader? false]]
choose-leaders
end

to choose-leaders
ask n-of ((percent_of_leader / 100) * population ) turtles
[
set leader? true
set color black
set size 1
set shape "person"
set leader self
]
end

to go
ask turtles [follow-leader] 
tick
end

to follow-leader
if not leader? [ 
let nearby-leaders turtles with [leader? and distance myself < 3] 
if any? nearby-leaders 
[ set heading (towards min-one-of nearby-leaders [distance myself]) - random minimum-separation +           random minimum-separation
]]   
end
```

Comment: To get help, you'll need to post a specific question about a specific coding challenge you are facing — not just a broad description of your overall goal. With only the information given, there isn't much we can say besides "Go for it! And when you get stuck, show us your code and explain the exact difficulty you're having in making the next step."

Comment: @Seth Sorry for the confiusion.  I just edited the code , what I expect the code to do is,  if 2 or more agents face the same leader, they should have minimum separation to each other at least 1patch,so that they will not be overlapped. The problem now, when I add the code 'while other turtles here [fd 1]`, seem like they are not following the leader in a que, instead going random forward . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The correct form of:

```
while other turtles here [fd 1]
```

is:

```
while any? other turtles-here [fd 1]
```

This isn't a minimum-separation rule exactly. It ensures that the turtle will keep moving until it is no longer sharing a patch with any other turtles. But the turtle might still be arbitrarily close to another turtle, if the two turtles are close to a patch boundary, but on opposite sides. Nonetheless, it might be good enough for your purposes.

An example model where turtles follow leaders at a uniform distance is Follower (more or less? not sure how uniform), in the Art section of Sample Models, in NetLogo's Models Library. You might look at that model and see if you think that approach might be applicable to your problem.

Comment: i have made some changes in the code. i add this code **[set heading (towards min-one-of nearby-leaders [distance myself]) - random minimum-separation + random minimum-separation
]]** instead of using this code "while any? other turtles-here [fd 1]", however i still not able to set minimum separation for each turtles that follow the same leader.They still overlapp.please help. tq

Comment: What method do you want to use to maintain the separation? If you have a method in mind, and you can express that method in English, then I can help you express it in code. But if you don't even have an idea for how it should work, well, I don't either.

Comment: i don't have any specific method need to use, as long as each turtles can keep certain distance between each other, should be good enough. what i have in mind, any follower(white turtle) find the nearest leader(black turtles), they heading will change to follow the leader's heading(follow where leader want to go). if they are two followers, facing the same leader, they can't be collide and need to keep certain distance. Actually, the concept same as flocking behavior, but this time, i add leader rule, so leader will guide flocking turtles to move to next place. thanks for the help.